# How to change values's position in 2d array in java?

Tags: java, arrays

i have given these matrix in java

```
name     class   
satish   BCA
Neeraj   MCA
```

how to rotate this to:

```
class  BCA     MCA
name   satish  neeraj
```

Comment: Add code snippet to make clear situation and get fast answer from community...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this function for the same:

```
public static String[][] transpose(String[][] m){
    String[][] temp = new String[m[0].length][m.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < m[0].length; j++)
            temp[j][i] = m[i][j];
    return temp;
}
```

Hope it helps.